Which is cost efficient?Azure backup and Snapshots, when backup is stopped and retain for 6 months?
My VM is in the stopped state(deallocated). But i want to keep the last backup data for 6 months and stop backup. So which is the best option to take retain backup data or take snapshot. Which is the better option and cost efficient in Azure?It would be helpful for me, if i get a help.

Given that your VM is in a stopped state, and you want to keep the last backup data for 6 months, using snapshots may be more cost-efficient, especially if there are minimal changes to the data during that period.
If you choose to stop protection and retain backup data, Azure Backup will keep the recovery points for you. However, you will incur costs for keeping the recovery points in the vault. The pricing for Azure Backup is based on the amount of data stored and the number of recovery points retained.
Snapshots are read-only point-in-time copies of your disk. They are billed based on the differential storage usage, meaning you only pay for the changes made since the last snapshot. This can be more cost-effective if you are only making small changes to your VM over time.
However, if you need to retain multiple recovery points or have a larger amount of data, retaining backup data might be more suitable despite the costs.
Now up to you which suits your requirement best
References:

Manage Azure VM backups with Azure Backup service
Backup and disaster recovery for Azure managed disks

